# Redirect output of script to multiple log files within the script

Tags: bash, logging, output, io-redirection

So there are a ton of questions about redirecting output. But I haven't been able to find an answer to this scenario.

Suppose I have a script like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_other_function1() {
  printf "THIS IS A FAKE FUNCTION"

}


_build_libMesh() {

  if eval "${__FULL_PATH}/moose/scripts/update_and_rebuild_libmesh.sh" | tee libmesh_build.log; then
    _debug printf ">> libMesh built successfully!\\n"
  else
    _die "libMesh build failed! Check 'libmesh_build.log'\\n"
  fi
}


_other_function2(){
  printf "THIS IS A FAKE FUNCTION TOO"
}


_build_app() {
  if eval "$(make -j "${_JOBS}")" | tee build_app.log; then
    _debug printf ">> ${_CODE_NAME} built successfully!\\n"
  else
    _die "${_CODE_NAME} build failed! Check 'build_app.log'.\\n"
  fi
}

_main() {
  _other_function1
  _build_libmesh
  _other_function2
  _build_app
}

if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "${0}" ]]; then
  _parse_options "${@}"
  _main |& tee nicmma.log
fi
```

I essentially want the entire script output to the logfile, except for the output of two functions, I want those output to two different logfiles.

So then the `nicmma.log` would look like:

```
THIS IS A FAKE FUNCTION
>> libMesh built successfully!
THIS IS A FAKE FUNCTION TOO
CODE_NAME build failed! check 'build_app'.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the name of the log file to each function/method.
Then, use that filename to output the log to that file using the ">>" operator.

Be careful to use the ">>" operator, instead of ">" .
As you may be aware, ">>" appends to the end of the file, and ">" overwrites the file.